# branch.io invite and redeem

Tags: android, branch.io, referrals, firebase-invites

everything is working fine But on redeem click. The credit is not decreasing!

I'm using this method in a fragment!

```
redimbetn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(updateamt<100){
                Branch.getInstance().loadRewards(new Branch.BranchReferralStateChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStateChanged(boolean changed, BranchError error) {
                        Branch.getInstance().redeemRewards(1);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abhinav

This is Vatsal from branch.io

- Please make sure the user has enough credits for redeeming.

Also, try using this listener method to get the error you are receiving and share the logs:

```
  branch.redeemRewards(1, new BranchReferralStateChangedListener() {
          @Override
          public void onStateChanged(boolean changed, BranchError error) {
            if (error != null) {
              Log.i("RedeemTest", "branch redeem rewards failed. Caused by -" + error.getMessage());
            } else {
              if (changed) {
                Log.i("RedeemTest", "redeemed rewards = " + true);
              } else {
                Log.i("RedeemTest", "redeem rewards unknown error ");
              }
            }
          }
        });
```